# Removing duplicate data in a multi dimension array (associative array)

Tags: php, arrays, duplicates

I have three keys pointing to value of type array, in those array values I have duplicate values. How can I remove them?

```
array(3) {
["rock"]=>
array(4) {
[0]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(15) "Teleman Tickets"
  ["location"]=>
  string(20) "Concorde 2, Brighton"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-02-20"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "20:00:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "50.817321799999990"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-0.12304610000001"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(30) "rock,alternative,indie"
}
[1]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["title"]=>
  string(9) "Blink-182"
  ["location"]=>
  string(25) "Motorpoint Arena, Cardiff"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-07-03"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "18:00:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "51.478937400000010"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-3.17172289999996"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(14) "rock,metal"
}
[2]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["title"]=>
  string(5) "Ghost"
  ["location"]=>
  string(29) "O2 Forum Kentish Town, London"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-03-26"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "19:00:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "51.552197000000010"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-0.14196900000002"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(30) "rock,alternative,indie"
}
[3]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["title"]=>
  string(11) "Courteeners"
  ["location"]=>
  string(39) "Emirates Old Trafford, Lancashire C.C.C"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-05-27"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "16:00:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "53.456428000000000"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-2.28679699999998"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(30) "rock,alternative,indie"
 }
}
["alternative"]=>
array(4) {
[0]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["title"]=>
  string(15) "Teleman Tickets"
  ["location"]=>
  string(20) "Concorde 2, Brighton"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-02-20"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "20:00:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "50.817321799999990"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-0.12304610000001"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(30) "rock,alternative,indie"
}
[1]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "6"
  ["title"]=>
  string(6) "Sum 41"
  ["location"]=>
  string(23) "O2 Academy Leeds, Leeds"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-02-26"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "19:00:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "53.802188400000000"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-1.54713770000001"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(21) "alternative,indie"
}
[2]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["title"]=>
  string(5) "Ghost"
  ["location"]=>
  string(29) "O2 Forum Kentish Town, London"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-03-26"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "19:00:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "51.552197000000010"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-0.14196900000002"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(30) "rock,alternative,indie"
}
[3]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["title"]=>
  string(11) "Courteeners"
  ["location"]=>
  string(39) "Emirates Old Trafford, Lancashire C.C.C"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-05-27"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "16:00:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "53.456428000000000"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-2.28679699999998"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(30) "rock,alternative,indie"
 }
}
["sax"]=>
array(1) {
[0]=>
array(9) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "3"
  ["title"]=>
  string(9) "Take That"
  ["location"]=>
  string(22) "The SSE Hydro, Glasgow"
  ["event_date"]=>
  string(10) "2017-05-11"
  ["event_time"]=>
  string(8) "18:30:00"
  ["url"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["geo_lat"]=>
  string(18) "55.860156000000000"
  ["geo_long"]=>
  string(17) "-4.28525800000000"
  ["tags"]=>
  string(24) "pop,boy-band,sax"
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific about which elements you're trying to remove?

Comment: removing duplicates doesn't make sense since these duplicates are in different categories (tags). Instead, you should suggest a new structure to store your data.

Comment: I want to keep the intersection values of [ROCK], [ALTERNATIVE] and [SAX] those are the keys with values of type array, some of those values are repeated in other keys

Comment: how can I divide the main array into three sub arrays, and get to use array_diff(), just an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that if two bands have the same 'id' then they are identical

```
$unique_bands = array();
// if the master array is called bands    
foreach($bands as $genre){
    foreach($genre as $band){
        $unqiue_bands[$band['id']] = $band;
     }
}
```

Maybe put `$unique_bands = array_values(array_filter($unique_bands));` at the end to reindex the array

Comment: That is what I am looking for thank you Jake mr. Genius ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a solution on the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php#116302)... A person made a simple function to do exactly what you want.

Example array:

```
<?php 
$details = array( 
    0 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mike",    "num"=>"9876543210"), 
    1 => array("id"=>"2", "name"=>"Carissa", "num"=>"08548596258"), 
    2 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mathew",  "num"=>"784581254"), 
); 
?>
```

Function:

```
<?php 
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 

    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
} 
?>
```

You will have to fix it to work your for array dimension.

Comment: I love this community when you give a solutions, maybe you are wrong, no one comments that and you have -100 downvotes without knowing why, but none of them gave a solution...

Comment: the id in my case is [rock], [alternative] and [sax] its coming from database

Comment: thank you anyways I really appreciate your help I have an answer up there! :) the solution is in the other answer

Comment: Hi matiaslauriti. I initially downvoted it based on [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44168393/1), which really isn't even an answer. Since then you've copied and pasted code from the link, which is _better_, because at least it it's no longer link-only, but there's still no indication in your answer text as to what that code actually does.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thank you for your answer. You could have also written that so I would just give a better answer.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I usually refrain from commenting when I vote, because it seems like people will want to argue about it more often than not. (I don't mean to imply that you're like that, but just in general.)